# Is there an opensource framework for 3d canvas?

Tags: html, webgl, wxglcanvas

Is there an opensource framework to allow real-time rendering of textured polygons?  I want to display photo's in a 3d space.  I don't need many polygons (less than 100, but the more the better, of course)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about [Three.js](http://www.aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/) ?

It's simple, open source and powerful :). (http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/) (You can render with SVG, Canvas or WebGL)

Answer (score 7):

[WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/)

Comment: WebGL, looks awesome, and I can't wait for it be adopted, but I should mention that whatever framework needs to be available and working today

Comment: Just realized this question was three years old... =P

Comment: Should be a little more detail than WebGL but yep WebGL is the way to go, take a look at my Butterfly subdivision which uses WebGL & Html5 canvas tag to render the shape http://canvascode.co.uk/Projects/butterflysubdivision.html

Answer (score 2):

[Webkit's 3d transitions for CSS3 are hardware rendered on some browsers](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/Functions.html) (Chrome, newer releases of Mobile Safari for the iOS) thus making [3d canvas animations](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas3dtexture_0.2/) also [hardware](http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-on-iphone-ipod-touch) [accelerated](http://mir.aculo.us/2010/06/04/making-an-ipad-html5-app-making-it-really-fast/) (this is i think how [Google gets it's scaling to work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3666131/56145) on the iOS).

This is not open source but it will get you 3d canvas and on certain platforms, awesome performance.

Comment: The 3d transistions appear to only really be supported in Safari. I see that chrome is suppose to support it, but the latest version (6.0.4.472.63) doesn't render them properly.  For instance view this link in safari and chrome: http://webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/morphing-cubes.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://processingjs.org.

[Wikipedia-Quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing.js):

> Processing.js uses JavaScript to render 2D and 3D content on the HTML
>   canvas element, and is supported by browsers that have implemented
>   this element (the latest versions of Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Internet
>   Explorer 9, Safari and Google Chrome).